# How to get event from Google Calendar in Java?

Tags: java

I use this code for getting Google calendars list:

```
// Create a CalenderService and authenticate
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("j...@gmail.com", "mypassword");

// Send the request and print the response
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);
System.out.println("Your calendars:");
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
  CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
  System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

This code return me calendars list, but I need to get all events from this calendar about today. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the sample program to start with please use `..../private/full` to get the events from Calendar.

For example:

```
"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xxx@gmail.com/private/full");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the official GData API:

Try using the [`getFeed(Query query, …)`](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService.html#getFeed%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) overload with a [`CalendarQuery`](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/calendar/CalendarQuery.html) - that seems to let you specify the range for the start time of an event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a this default URL, instead of specifying xxx@gmail.com,

```
"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full"
```

And I think you should use `CalendarEventFeed` Object instead of `CalendarFeed`
See this code snippet below:

```
CalendarQuery myQuery = new CalendarQuery(feedUrl);
myService.setUserCredentials(p.getgUser(), p.getgPassword());

 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 myQuery.setMinimumStartTime(DateTime.now());
 myQuery.setMaximumStartTime(dt);

CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = myService.query(myQuery, CalendarEventFeed.class);
```

Then traverse the contents of `resultFeed`

.....

```
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = calendarData

for (int i = 0; i<calendarData.getEntries().size(); i++) {
          CalendarEventEntry entry = calendarData.getEntries().get(i);
```

.....